# Is there a way to search the Properties Window in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties, keyboard-shortcuts

The properties window can often become quite overwhelming with numerous items.
Is there a way to search its items in Visual Studio 2010 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the file type, there may already be a search box on the Proeprties window.  For example, for XAML documents, [there is a search box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171352.aspx) (see the item about Search at the bottom).  However, for C# documents, there is not, and there isn't a good way to search the properties without writing some kind of custom extension.

**Edit:**

Seeing as your question is about the overwhelming number of items in the properties window, have you tried switching between the *Categorized* and *Alphabetical* views of the properties?  That should help minimize the number of properties you have to look at at a given time.

Comment: @Jelly None that I'm aware of :(

Comment: @Jelly, have you tried using the *Categorized* view to help sort through the number of properties?

Comment: Wrong way around, I think, it is the *alphabetic* sort that helps quickly finding the property.

Comment: @Jelly  Either way :) those are the tools for dealing with the large number of properties that are built in

Answer (score 7):

Little late: The [RapidDesign](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c820e3a0-add2-4a43-943c-029e296ab00d) Extension has the ability to search the Designer Properties

Comment: but it only can use in vs2019 and it not free. Is there any choices on vs2022?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about 'Properties' or 'Options'? Unless you're working on a windows form or WPF project, there aren't that many things in Properties window. If you're looking to search 'Options', here is a great extension: [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

Maybe you can request for a feature here (to search Properties).

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for such thing for some time with no luck.

The best way I found is to set up properties in code (i.e. on OnLoad event) as editor allows to search by typing part of property name.